# JSON Array not displaying correct content on link click

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am bringing in JSON data via Ajax & Jquery. I have loaded up the data and the objects are as follows -

```
ID,
TITLE,
PERMALINK,
CONTENT, 
ETC.(The rest is not important)
```

I am trying to display EACH CONTENT object separately based on the link that you click. So if the link has a specific ID, then the CONTENT object in THAT array will display.

But what I am getting is - On every link I click, it displays the same CONTENT object no matter what.

I have attached the code snippets for you to look at and hopefully you see the problem, because I definitely cant.

I would really appreciate the help. Otherwise I might just rip my hair out.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json',
    data: {
        get_param: 'value'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, element) {
            var link = $('.more-link');
            var cont = "<div class='content'>" + data[i].content + "</div>";
            var back = "<a class='back' href='http://localhost:8888/postPopulate/Feb21.8.23AM'>BACK</a>";
            var thumb = "<img class='thumb' src=" + data[i].thumbnail + ">";
            var title = "<h1 class='title'>" + data[i].title + "</h1>";
            var exc = "<p class='excerpt'>" + data[i].excerpt + "</p>";
            var perma = JSON.stringify(data[i].permalink);

            perma = perma.replace("http://www.capetownetc.com/blog/", "");
            perma = perma.replace("http://www.capetownetc.com/events/", "");
            perma = perma.replace("http://www.capetownetc.com/mykitchen/", "");
            $(link).attr("href", "http://localhost:8888/postPopulate/Feb21.8.23AM/#" + perma);
            console.log(perma);

            $(link).click(function () {
                $('body').html(cont);
                $('body').append(back);
            });

            $('body').append(title);
            $('body').append(thumb);
            $('body').append(exc);
        }); //END OF FOR LOOP
    } //END OF SUCCESS FUNC
}); //END OF AJAX
```

JSON example

```js
[{
    "id": 58543,
    "title": "Art@Almenkerk brings contemporary art to the wine estate",
    "permalink": "http:\/\/www.capetownetc.com\/blog\/artalmenkerk-brings-contemporary-art-wine-estate\/",
    "content": "With its spectacular views and award-winning wine, a trip to Almenkerk Wine Estate in Elgin is well worth it...",
    "excerpt": "With its spectacular views and award-winning wine, a trip to Almenkerk Wine Estate in Elgin is well worth it...",
    "date": "2017-02-20 10:00:34",
    "author": "Annzra Denita",
    "thumbnail": "http:\/\/www.capetownetc.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/02\/Almenekerk-FI.jpg 650w, http:\/\/www.capetownetc.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/02\/Almenekerk-FI-600x400.jpg 600w",
    "categories": ["blog", "CULTURE"],
    "tags": ["art", "arts", "cape town etc", "capetown etc", "CapeTownEtc", "culture", "elgin", "getaways", "sculpture", "wine"]
  },
  //...
]
```

UPDATE -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rugby Thumbnails</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main2.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body>

    
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on link, it only displays content1

[image]

Comment: I think the css code is irrelevant here, also the `script` tag in the html code, shouldn't it be in `head` section ?(it's even outside `<html></html>`)

Comment: Yes it is, you can look past that. It doesnt seem to be outside. I understand what you are saying, but the script doesnt need any elements in the HTML, so it's irrelevant to the problem. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: did you verify that the server returns the json response you expect ? is it returning different content for each link ?(you can see that using your browser's developer tools )

Comment: Yes I did, if I console log it and check the network, I am getting what I want. I can send a screenshot of the console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Your link click

```
 $(link).click(function () {
                $('body').html(cont);
                $('body').append(back);
            });
```

should be outside of ajax success function, as giving it in each loop binding click event multiple time. it is wrong.
You need to give parent reference on "more-link" click and find its siblings ".content" put it as html and then find its sibling ".back" and append it to html.

You code link click should look something like like this

```
$("body").on("click",".more-link",function () {
var content = $(this).siblings(".content");
var back = $(this).siblings(".back");
                    $('body').html(content);  // it may be differ based on your html structure
                    $('body').append(back);
                });
```

You can search for giving click event on dynamically generated element if problem occurs for click event as your appending element dynamically to DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have inserted the HTML, not sure why it didnt add the first time. But if I take the click function out of the ajax call, both Data and i are undefined because the ajax call is not global. I'm not sure how to correct this.

Comment: You don't need to remove $(each) code.
you only need to put 
$(link).click(function ()) out side of your ajax call and put in directly in document.ready() and modify it, as like I suggested in answer.